# How to remove nav-bar from custom magento admin page?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1

I want to remove navbar from a custom magento admin panel popup. I have already removed header and footer, but can not remove navbar panel.

Please help

```
<remove name="footer" />

<remove name="header" />
<remove name="top.menu" />
<remove name="top.links" />
<remove name="top.container" />


<reference name="content">
    <remove name="nav-bar" />
    <remove name="header" />
    <block type="core/template" name="xyz" template="abc/test/test.phtml" />
</reference>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simple way,But I don't know this is better way or not but it's working.

Go to

C:\Xampp\htdocs\your project\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\page\menu.phtml

Then comment or delete the menu like as below

```
<div class="nav-bar">
<!-- menu start -->
<?php //echo $this->getMenuLevel($this->getMenuArray()); ?>
<!-- menu end -->

    <a id="page-help-link" href="<?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getPageHelpUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Get help for this page') ?></a>
    <script type="text/javascript">$('page-help-link').target = 'magento_page_help'</script>

</div>
```

After changed the code please clear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way for hide the top menu of admin panel in magento.

Please  follow the below steps:

open file adminhtml.xml ;
Location : /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/etc/adminhtml.xml

Note : It is core file so,please override this module(best way).

```
   <!-- Custom work for hide admin menu links -->

     <catalog translate="title"> 
        <depends><config>HideMe</config></depends>
    </catalog>

     <system translate="title"> 
        <depends><config>HideMe</config></depends>
    </system>

     <sales translate="title"> 
        <depends><config>HideMe</config></depends>
    </sales>

         <promo translate="title"> 
        <depends><config>HideMe</config></depends>
    </promo>


    <report translate="title">
        <depends><module>HideMe</module></depends>
    </report>

     <customer translate="title">
        <depends><module>HideMe</module></depends>
    </customer>

    <newsletter translate="title">
        <depends><module>HideMe</module></depends>
    </newsletter>

    <cms translate="title" module="adminhtml">
        <depends><module>HideMe</module></depends>
    </cms>
       <!--Custom work for hide admin menu links end-->
```

It's working  fine.

Thanks
Pradeep kumar